# check listener status other than 1521

Tags: oracle-11g, listener

I have two listners: 

one is running on port 1521 another on 1531. 

`lsnrctl stat` shows status of services running on port 1521 only.

How should I check whether the services running on port 1531 is proper or not.

Listner Entry:

```
    # listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
    # Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

    ADMIN_RESTRICTIONS_LISTENER = ON

    LISTENER =
      (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
        (DESCRIPTION =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
        )
        (DESCRIPTION =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
          (PROTOCOL_STACK =
            (PRESENTATION = GIOP)
            (SESSION = RAW)
          )
        )
      )

    ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\Administrator

    SID_LIST_PARIVARTAN =
      (SID_LIST =
        (SID_DESC =
          (GLOBAL_DBNAME = PARIVARTAN)
          (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
          (PROGRAM = extproc)
          (SID_NAME = PARIVARTAN)
        )
      )


    PARIVARTAN =
      (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
        (DESCRIPTION =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1531))
        )
      )

    ADR_BASE_PARIVARTAN = C:\app\Administrator
```

TNSNAMES Entry

```
    # tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
    # Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

    ORCL =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
        )
      )

    PARIVARTAN =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1531))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVICE_NAME = parivartan)
        )
      )
```

`tns ping` result:

```
    Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
    Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
    (HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1531))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = parivartan)))
    OK (10 msec)
```

Comment: Hang on - did you fix your database (I'm just looking at the other question you posted on the site)???

Comment: i have posted my tns entry file and listener file kindly check if there is something i have missed...

Comment: Did you fix your database?? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30542/listener-error-not-connecting You don't need a new listener to fix that.

Comment: that is fixed actually due to some protection issue i can not use 1521 port. that's why using 1531 port and getting this issue...

Answer (score 4):

Run:

```
lsnrctl status LISTENERNAME
```

... where `LISTENERNAME` is the name of the listener that is listening on port 1531. You can get this name from your `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora` file.

For example:

```
LISTENER1531 =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = node1)(PORT = 1531))
      )
    )
  )
```

`LISTENER1531` would be the listener name for the above `listener.ora` entry.

If you need to add databases to the listener, add an entry to the `listener.ora`, as follows:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER1531 =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = YOURDB)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (SID_NAME = YOURDB)
    )
  )
```

Obviously you'll need to add your own database and listener names & change the path to your `$ORACLE_HOME`.

You can reload the listener config with:

```
lsnrctl reload LISTENER1531
```

The above works fine for me with a `tnsnames.ora as follows:

```
YOURDB =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = node1)(Port = 1531))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = YOURDB)
 )
)
```

Comment: Following is the response: Listening Endpoints Summary... (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1531))) The listener supports no services The command completed successfully. Although i have service name in tns file

Comment: Have you got a `SID_LIST_<YOURLISTENERNAME> =` entry in your listener.ora? If not, make one or use `netca` to help you do so. I've edited the answer with help.

Comment: no i don't have such entry. will u provide me the sample entry for the same

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Now lsnrctl show's the status as UNKNOWN. also when i try to connect it gives me following error: ORA-28547: connection to server failed, probable Oracle Net admin error

Comment: Edit your question with copies of your `listener.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` entries.

Comment: A status of `UNKNOWN` just means that the DB connection is manually stated in the `listener.ora` rather than registered automatically by the database.

Comment: So what will be the next step is all entries are proper ??

Comment: Edit your post with the output of `tnsping PARIVARTAN`.